# Java List and collection Abstract method do not specify a body

Tags: java, interface, java-collections-api

I have an assignment which I have a class that implements `java.util.List`

```
public class DSCircularList implements List
```

In assignment sheet it says that I have to implement public interface `Collection` and public interface `List`. One of the methods I have to implement is:

```
public int size ();
```

when I try to implement it like:

```
public int size() { 
    return size;
}
```

when I add curly braces it show the error

> Abstract method do not specify a body

if someone can help me.

Comment: As your `DSCircularList` class is not an `abstract` class but a concrete class, you need to implement all the methods of your `List` interface and any interface that `List` extends, in this case `Collection` interface, if you really create a list class of your own, try extending `AbstractList` rather than trying to implement all the methods

Comment: Can I clarify the question? Do you mean `java.util.List` and `java.util.Collection` or are you meant to write your own interfaces with these names?

Comment: I have classes which are already written and  I only have to add  a body, but I think I will sit and read more about abstract class. Thank you guys for trying to help maybe later I will ask again :)

Comment: Method declaration goes in `Interface(List or Collection)` and implemented in `Conrcrete class (DSCircularList )`

Comment: Removed unneeded text and fixed some grammar

Answer (score 2):

This error is coming because you are trying to implement method in interface List. Mark that interface doesn't have a method body. If you want to implement size() method then you need to implement it in your DSCircularList class.

you need to implement size method like:

in Collection.java file,

```
public interface Collection{
     public int size();
}
```

Extending Collection interface in List interface,
List.java file:

```
public interface List extends Collection{
    //it extends size() method structure from Collection interface which needs to implement in any non abstract class.
    //any extra method structures of List interface
}
```

implementing your List class in DSCircularList class,
DSCircularList.java file

```
public class DSCircularList implements List{

    public static void main(String[] arg0){

    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

so, by this you can make your own Collection interface, List interface and implement it in your code.